# Is there any way to combine/simplify interpolation curves?

Tags: animation

To put things bluntly, 5 curves per bone has always intimidated me. 
In short my questions are:

Can I combine curves in to one master curve?

If not what is the best way to simplify this workflow?

I've been looking for a solution to this for a while, if I've been dumb and missed an obvious google search can someone point me in the right direction? :)

Comment: How are you getting 5 curves per bone? In quaternion mode bones have 4 rotation channels and in euler mode, they have 3. Location and Scale also have 3 (XYZ) values.

Comment: sorry, you're right. Clearly I'm still a noob at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An fcurve that you see in the [graph editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html) is able to animate only one value throughout an animation. As you follow the curve from left to right, it's x,y location gets translated to the frame and value for the property being animated.

For an object (or armature bone...) you can have one fcurve for the x-location, another for the y-location, one for x-scale and so on, meaning up to nine curves for the loc/rot/scale. You may also have extra fcurves for an object if you have other properties animated, like visibility, shape keys, modifiers, constraints...

While you need an fcurve for each value that you want to animate, you don't have to have an fcurve for every possible value, you only need an fcurve for each property you want to control during an animation. When you insert a keyframe using <kbd>I</kbd>*->Location* blender will create three fcurves for the location. You can also <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on the x-location display and choose Insert Single Keyframe to only create one fcurve. If you then use <kbd>I</kbd>*->Available* only the values with existing fcurves will get new keyframes.

[image: insert a single property keyframe]

If you have excess fcurves that you don't want, you can delete single fcurves in the graph editor. With the fcurve name selected and the mouse over the list press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete the entire fcurve.

When you have multiple fcurves, you can also simplify the graph editor display to make it easier to work with. For each fcurve and each group of curves, there is a small eye icon that can show/hide the fcurve or groups of fcurves. The cursor in the header allows only selected items to be listed in the graph editor, while the magnifying glass to it's right allows you to filter by name.

[image: graph editor]